# Mysql Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error while inserting data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having This error while trying to save data to mysql and i cant see any error here

```
$cons_no = $_POST['cons_no'];
$ship_name = $_POST['ship_name'];
$ship_location = $_POST['ship_location'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$s_add = $_POST['s_add'];
$r_name = $_POST['r_name'];
$r_phone = $_POST['r_phone'];
$r_add = $_POST['r_add'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$weight = $_POST['weight'];
$invoice_no = $_POST['invoice_no'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$book_mode = $_POST['book_mode'];
$freight = $_POST['freight'];
$mode = $_POST['mode'];
$pick_date = $_POST['pick_date'];
$pick_time = $_POST['pick_time'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$r_country = $_POST['r_country'];
```

**The only this not in the code is the cid which is auto increment**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_courier (cons_no, ship_name, ship_location, phone, s_add, r_name, r_phone, r_add,  type, weight, invoice_no, qty, book_mode, freight, mode, pick_date, pick_time, status, comments, r_country)
        VALUES('$cons_no', '$ship_name', '$ship_location', '$phone', '$s_add', '$r_name', '$r_phone', '$r_add', '$type', '$weight', $invoice_no, '$qty', '$freight', '$mode', '$pick_date', '$pick_time', '$status', '$comments', '$r_country')";
```

Comment: book_mode .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your builded SQL string, but I can assume you have empty values.. to prevent that you can add additional check before assign a value.

```
$status = isset($_POST['status'])?$_POST['status']:0; // default 0 if don't exists
```

Edit:

I see your query, the answer is: **the field `book_mode` is missing in values sentence**